# Specify an Outlook rule condition based on words in the sender's address

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867147(v=office.14).aspx), I should be able to specify a condition in my Outlook Rule that matches based on a partial string match of the sender address by specifying the text to match in `TextRuleCondition.Text` on the condition of type `olConditionSenderAddress`:

[image: screenshot from msdn]

But, I cannot find the appropriate property to set within the [`Rule.Conditions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869688(v=office.14).aspx) object.  If I enumerate a newly created rule's conditions, there is no existing condition of type `TextRuleCondition` having `ConditionType == olConditionSenderAddress`.  The only condition with the correct `ConditionType` is an `AddressRuleCondition`, which has no `Text` property.

How do I programmatically specify a condition in an Outlook 2010 rule where the sender address contains a certain string?

Comment: Will this rule be running for messages that are sent or messages that are received (*or both*)?

Comment: This rule is for messages that are received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Conditions.SenderAddress` rule condition and use its address property like bellow:

```
Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim oAddressRuleCondition As Outlook.AddressRuleCondition

Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
Set oRule = colRules.Create("Sender Rule", olRuleReceive)
Set oAddressRuleCondition = oRule.Conditions.SenderAddress

With oAddressRuleCondition 

    .Enabled = True
    .Address = Array("example")

End With

.....

colRules.Save
```